# Sorting complex Array of Objects and Objects again contain an Array

Tags: javascript

I know sorting question is asked many a time but I am facing a little different problem, I have already searched and tried different things, but not successful in sorting my array. Can someone help me with this, your help will be greatly appreciable. I am new to programming.

Here is my array:-

```
var People = [
        {Name: [ {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
                 {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
                 {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}], Middlename: "JJ"},

          {Name: [ {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
                 {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
                 {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}], Middlename:"Abrams"},
          {Name: [ {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
                 {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
                 {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}], Middlename: "Wars"},
         {Name: [ {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
                 {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
                 {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
                {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}], Middlename: "Wars"}

];
```

Here What I have tried:-

```
doSorting: function(People) {

        for(var x = 0; x < People.length; x++){
          for(var y=0;y<People.Name.length; y ++){
            People.Name[y] = People.Name[y].sort(function(obj1,obj2){
              return obj1.surname.split("-")[0] - obj2.surname.split("-")[0];
            });
          }

        }

        return People;
    }
    console.log(People);
```

Comment: You did not even tell us _how_ you want those items sorted …

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? can you explain please

Comment: @izengod I am trying to sort it with based on surname

Comment: @CBroe I want to want to sort it based on "surname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since parseInt() and parseFloat() will also truncate everything in a string after the number, you can also write:

```
People.forEach(group => {
  group.Name.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.surname) - parseInt(b.surname))
})
```

```js
var People = [
  {
    Name: [
      {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
      {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}
    ], 
    Middlename: "JJ"
  },
  {
    Name: [
      {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
      {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}
    ], 
    Middlename:"Abrams"
  },
  {
    Name: [
      {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
      {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}
    ], 
    Middlename: "Wars"
  },
  {
    Name: [
      {name: "Name", surname: "100-150"},
      {name: "AAA", surname: "1-10"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "251-300"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "10-99"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "201-250"},
      {name: "Name", surname: "152-200"}
    ], 
    Middlename: "Wars"
  }
];

People.forEach(group => {
  group.Name.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.surname) - parseInt(b.surname))
})

console.log(People);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got one loop too many. `People.Name[y]` (which needs to be `People[x].Name[y]` anyway) is not an array that you can sort, it's an individual object. You'll want

```
for (var x = 0; x < People.length; x++){
    People[x].Name.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        return obj1.surname.split("-")[0] - obj2.surname.split("-")[0];
    });
}
```

That will sort each of the inner arrays (on its own) by the first number in the surname.

Comment: I think you meant `People[x].Name.sort`

Comment: @HarshGupta Thanks, indeed it needs to be that

Comment: @Bergi I just tried it but it is not working as expected, it says can not read property "split"

Comment: @JustStartedProgramming It does work with the `People` object you posted. Are you sure all the objects to be sorted in the actual data do have a `surname`?

Comment: @JustStartedProgramming Well then you should have posted such actual data in the question… Regardless, how do you want to sort items without a surname?

Comment: @Bergi OK I will think about it